# Find max value by group in google sheets

Tags: sorting, google-sheets, indexing, match, vlookup

Let's assume I have data like this and I'd like to fond the max value on a column an repeat for all the others within the same group:
[image]

What coul i put on Result as formula to obtain the desired result? Is there a way to obtain this result without ordering the data first?

Comment: Sounds like you may benefit from [MAXIFS](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7013817?hl=en)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use:

```
=INDEX(VLOOKUP(A2:A&B2:B, SORT({A2:A&B2:B, C2:C}, 2, ), 2, ))
```

[image]